# Is it safe to use Java Threads in the same way as desktop applications?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

The Android must manage the thread or can be used a code like this:

```
public class GameThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        while (!finished) {

            //game work

            try {
                Thread.sleep(fps);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Interruptions here are no big deal.
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sleeping to achieve some fps seems like a very bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Thread` directly but there are some catches in Android

- Do not block the UI thread
- ***Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread***

Android documentation on [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) provides ample guidelines to help you get started.

### Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user
>   interface. It performs the blocking operations in a worker thread and
>   then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to
>   handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Android has its own Threading model and framework, which is much more sophisticated than plain Java. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) explains everything you need.